# Is there a way to know that a user has blue tick on facebook using the facebook SDK for Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to implement functionality where as soon as a user logs in to my application using his/her Facebook credentials (via Facebook SDK), I can recognize if they have a blue tick or not, that is if they are a public profile or not.

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you check out the api reference?

Comment: @luschn yes I read it out but could not figure out how it can help.

Comment: if there is nothing about it in the api reference (see the "user" page), what does that tell you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            boolean verified = object.getBoolean("is_verified");
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: I'll try this out asap!